# php searching through a multi-dimension array across more than one field

Tags: php

I have a multi-dimension array (containing subject_code, subject_name and grade).  I need to extract the subject_code when given the grade and the subject name. There are many replies on Stackoverflow relating to **array_search** but only searching by one field.  Is there a more elegant way of performing this search rather than the "trawling" code I have below:

```
function get_subject_code($subjects_array, $count_subs, $grade, $subject) {
    for($i=0;$i<$count_subs;$i++){
        if (($subjects_array[$i]['grade'] == $grade) && ($subjects_array[$i]['subject'] == $subject) ){
            $lesson = $subjects_array[$i]['coursecode'];
        }
    }
    return $lesson;
}
```

Comment: post the array structure, what you need or no one can help you

Answer (score 0):

you can array_filter like this,

```
$lessons = array_column(array_filter($subjects_array, function($v) use($grade, $subject){
  return $v['grade'] == $grade && $v['subject'] == $subject;
}), 'subject_code');
```